In eval(.expr_beta_arg) : invalid value for 'beta' : the argument is taken to be "none"
I encountered this problem when using dredge of the mumin package to calculate AIC value ordering of mixed effects models
library(mumin)
analysis1 <- lmerTest::lmer(scale(resistance) ~ scale(diameter) * angleclass + (1 | classify10), data = total)

analysis1_tree_test  <- dredge(analysis1, evaluate = TRUE, rank = "AICc",REML=F,options(na.action = "na.fail")) 

# Fixed term is "(Intercept)"
# Warning messages:
# 1: In class(object) <- "environment" :
#   Setting class(x) to "environment" sets attribute to NULL; result will no longer be an S4 object
# 2: In class(object) <- "environment" :
#   Setting class(x) to "environment" sets attribute to NULL; result will no longer be an S4 object
# 3: In eval(.expr_beta_arg) :
#   invalid value for 'beta' : the argument is taken to be "none"


Welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This post may help.
